# Legal to overwrite std::string's null terminator?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdstring

In C++11, we know that `std::string` is guaranteed to be both contiguous and null-terminated (or more pedantically, terminated by `charT()`, which in the case of `char` is the null character 0).

There is this C API I need to use that fills in a string by pointer. It writes the whole string + null terminator. In C++03, I was always forced to use a `vector<char>`, because I couldn't assume that `string` was contiguous or null-terminated. But in C++11 (assuming a properly conforming `basic_string` class, which is still iffy in some standard libraries), I can.

Or can I? When I do this:

```
std::string str(length);
```

The string will allocate `length+1` bytes, with the last filled in by the null-terminator. That's good. But when I pass this off to the C API, it's going to write `length+1` characters. It's going to overwrite the null-terminator.

Admittedly, it's going to overwrite the null-terminator *with a null character*. Odds are good that this will work (indeed, I can't imagine how it *couldn't* work).

But I don't care about what "works". I want to know, *according to the spec*, whether it's OK to overwrite the null-terminator with a null character?

Comment: Does a null character not equal a null terminator? Wouldn't they both be '\0' or ASCII value 0?

Comment: @Nox: A null terminator is what you call the null *character* that goes at the end of the string, to signal that it is the end of the string.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a bad thing. As long it is a null character so that C can see it is the end of a string it shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: Right, but @NicolBolas's question is not "does it cause a problem", but "does the spec allow for it".

Comment: Why not allowed? You get the pointer to the null terminator and just change it. I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @texasbruce In other words, who cares what the spec allows, if it works on your system use it? Luckily, not everyone has that attitude.

Comment: It should be possible to avoid the problem by using a `std::string` with an extra null character at the end, with length `length + 1`, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: C family can do sorta direct memory read and write by using pointer. That's why it is medium level opposed to high level. Any C background programmer will tell you this overwrite is perfectly normal.

Comment: @texasbruce That is utterly irrelevant. The point is that nothing in the standard guarantees that the null termination is at a writeable memory location at all. It’s entirely possible (if unlikely) that it’s in read-only memory, for instance. Then any attempt to write to it will crash the program. Any competent C programmer will tell you that you are stark raving mad if you attempt to write portable programs that ignore these effects. It is *not* “perfectly normal” at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's perfectly possible that not being portable to all platforms is a conscious design decision, in which case you can make more assumptions, so you don't need to bother with what the spec says because all that matters is what your compiler and your libraries actually implement.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Agreed. But that’s a completely different discussion. And even then it doesn’t pay to ignore what the spec says: you may still consciously decide to *break* the spec – but you should know it first.

Comment: Sure thing. Let the standard rule everything. EOC.

Comment: This is subject of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/ynde19RQVIw/NxlBKXQ419IJ

Comment: "In C++11, we know that std::string is guaranteed to be both contiguous and null-terminated" Where does the standard guarantee that the `std::string` is null-terminated? The standard does say it's null terminated if you call '.c_str()` or `.data()`, but where is it stated that it's guaranteed to be null terminated always?

Comment: @Ayxan: It's inferred; essentially, the standard defines things in a way that it's impossible to implement `string` such that the string *isn't* NUL-terminated. `data` returns a pointer such that `p + i` is equal to what you get from `&operator[](i)` within a *closed* range `[0, size()]`. That pointer therefore must itself be NUL-terminated. Further, `data` may not invalidate pointers/iterators to the character sequence, so it cannot allocate a NUL-terminated string when it gets called. The only valid implementation left is to always NUL-terminate the string.

Comment: @NicolBolas an implementation could always have room for one more character in the buffer than the size of the string and add NUL when `.data` or `.c_str` is called. So it's technically possible for a confirming implementation of `std::string` to not be NUL terminated all the time.

Comment: @Ayxan: No it couldn't, because `*(&operator[](size() - 1) + 1)` is required to work (obviously if `size() > 0`) and be the NUL-character. Also, what exactly would be the point of such an implementation? Also, `c_str` is `const`, and in the standard library, calling a `const` function on the same object from two different threads has to be thread-safe. So if a `const` function mutates the stored data, it would need to be done behind a mutex or other synchronization primitive, or otherwise guarantee that the two writes won't interfere with one-another.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't know `*(&operator[](size() - 1) + 1)` was guaranteed to be NUL. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[LWG 2475](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2475) made this valid by editing the specification of `operator[](size())` (inserted text in bold):

> Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value
>   `charT()`, where modifying the object **to any value other than `charT()`**
>   leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see how this resolves the situation: It means you can write `s[s.size()] = '\0';` but it is still not defined (in C++14) that `&s[s.size() - 1] + 1` is dereferencable (let alone yielding a null terminator); so by extension an algorithm that starts at `&s[0]` and increments a `char *` still can't read or write the null terminator. The section [string.require]/4 only defines this pointer arithmetic for the index being strictly less than the size.

Comment: @M.M. That's hidden in the specification of `data()`.

Comment: I agree that if `data()` is used as the source of the pointer then it's all good, however I don't see where `&s[0]` gives the same guarantee.  Specifically, I don't see anything preventing the implementation not writing the null terminator until `data()` or `c_str()` is actually called (and either writing it or using a dummy for the `&s[s.size()]` case).

Comment: @M.M Then file an LWG issue. The intent here is pretty clear, so if the wording doesn't match it's in the "obvious defect" category.

Comment: I don't know why LWG 2475 is being referred to in past tense, the [status report](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-status.html) shows that it is not yet resolved.

Comment: @T.C.: Just grabbed the latest draft, the wording change leaves things... weird?  inconsistent?  Going to study the proposal in detail.

Comment: And there in the notes on the proposal: "Tues PM: This should also apply to non-const `data()`. Billy to update wording."  Looks like that hasn't happened, leaving overwriting the terminator still illegal, if done by pointer arithmetic instead of calling the string's `operator[]()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It should be noted that the current status (updated on this day) of 2475 is "C++17". So the committee seems to believe that it has been resolved and added to C++17.

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, this is UB, if I interpret the wording correct (in any case, it's not allowed):

`§21.4.5 [string.access] p2`

> *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; **the referenced value shall not be modified**.

(Editorial error that it says `T` not `charT`.)

`.data()` and `.c_str()` basically point back to `operator[]` (`§21.4.7.1 [string.accessors] p1`):

> *Returns:* A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.

Comment: Does writing '\0' into something which is already '\0' actually count as modifying it?

Comment: I’m not sure what to make of this: since `data()` returns a pointer, `str.data()[str.size()]` is clearly **not** just a reference, it’s a bona fide allocated `CharT` object, and as such can safely be written to. But unfortunately `data()` returns a constant string so it cannot be modified anyway. Getting a pointer to a modifiable string via `&str[0]` yields a pointer to a modifiable contiguous buffer but is there a guarantee that `*(&str[0] + str.size())` is writeable? Not as far as I can see.

Comment: @Konrad: Why should `data()[size()]` *not* be a reference?

Comment: @Xeo Oh, it is of course. But it’s a reference to an object in the same underlying buffer.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, yes, definitely. It writes to memory.

Comment: @Konrad: Not necessarily when access as `operator[](size())`, it seems. :)

Comment: @Xeo But it’s not accessing `operator[]`. What you get back from `data()` is a raw pointer to `CharT`, it cannot call `string::operator[]`. That’s what I meant. Not that it really helps here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, `data` and `c_str` return const pointers, so they are out of the question for modifying, anyway. And from 21.4.5 p2 it doesn't really follow that `*(&str[0] + str.size())` is even allowed, since `[]` is only equal to `*(begin()+pos)` for `pos < size()`. I think an implementation is perfectly allowed to hold the string data in a `length` array together with an additional `static const charT` member for the null (of course this means it would have to maintain an additional buffer to return by `data` and `c_str`, but why not?).

Comment: @ChristianRau That’s what I was alluding to, yes. Although in fact the spec guarantees that constructing a string of length `n` will generate a buffer of length `n + 1` with `data()` pointing to its beginning. So the buffer does exist, as you were implying. But the spec says nothing about whether `str[str.size()]` will still point into that buffer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It has to. The buffer is *contiguous*. Therefore, `&str[str.size() - 1] == &str[str.size()] - 1` must be true (assuming `length()` is at least 1). If it weren't, then the buffer wouldn't be contiguous.

Comment: @NicolBolas No. `size()` is an invalid argument for `operator[]` so nothing guarantees that its return value will point to the buffer. For instance (far-fetched), `operator[]` could contain the following logic: `static CharT terminator{}; if (index == size()) return terminator; else return _data[i];`.

Comment: @Konrad how does that implementation maintain the requirements of `data`? ("*Returns*: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`")

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ah, it’s comparing addresses. That changes everything. In that case, I’m tempted to just ignore the spec here …

Comment: @ChristianRau: In C++11, an implementation is *required* to return the same underlying buffer for `data()` and `c_str()` too, which means your thought "(*of course this means it would have to maintain an additional buffer to return by data and c_str, **but why not?***)" is going stray!.

Comment: Uh, **what returns this**?  I presume it is `operator[]`, but you forgot to actually say that.  Also note that the C function won't overwrite the location `&s[s.size()]`, it will overwrite `&s[0] + size()`.

Answer (score 10):

According to the spec, overwriting the terminating `NUL` should be *undefined behavior*.
So, the right thing to do would be to allocate `length+1` characters in the string, pass the string buffer to the C API, and then `resize()` back to `length`:

```
// "+ 1" to make room for the terminating NUL for the C API
std::string str(length + 1);

// Call the C API passing &str[0] to safely write to the string buffer
...

// Resize back to length
str.resize(length);
```

(FWIW, I tried the "overwriting NUL" approach on MSVC10, and it works fine.)

---

**EDIT 2024-FEB-27**: Since 2012 (the year in which this question was originally asked and answered here) the C++ standard has been modified, and **since C++17** it's legal to overwrite `std::string`'s `NUL` terminator with another `NUL`.

Comment: I’d go with this solution as well. But it’s unsatisfying that this requires a totally needless allocation of an extra character. Why didn’t the spec just make the null termination writeable?

Comment: Because that would mean more typing? 'You must not overwrite the null, except with another null'.  Perhaps their fingers were getting tired, or it was the end of the day and the bars were open.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree that the standard should be changed, making it possible to overwrite a `NUL` with another `NUL`. I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible or should trigger undefined behavior, and I don't like the needless allocation of an extra character either.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose n3092 isn't current any more but that's what I have.  Section 21.4.5 allows access to a single element.  It requires pos <= size().  If pos < size() then you get the actual element, otherwise (i.e. if pos == size()) then you get a non-modifiable reference.

I think that as far as the programming language is concerned, a kind of access which could modify the value is considered a modification even if the new value is the same as the old value.

Does g++ have a pedantic library that you can link to?

Comment: libstdc++ has a [debug mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html) but there are limits to what it will diagnose. It validates iterator operations, but can't notice writes of individual bytes through pointers.