# Convert std::wstring to WCHAR*

Tags: c++, string

I have no idea how to convert a  `std::wstring` to a `WCHAR*`

```
std::wstring wstrProcToSearch;
WCHAR * wpProcToSearch = NULL;

std::wcin >> wstrProcToSearch;  // input std::wstring
// now i need to convert the wstring to a WCHAR*
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str ... assuming `const WCHAR *` is acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with `const wchat_t*`? What do you want to do with it? And I really hate those Windows types! We don't need `WCHAR`!

Comment: Do you want to convert to `WCHAR*` or to `const WCHAR*`? i.e. do you want _read-only_ access (`const WCHAR*`) to `std::wstring`'s content, or do you _modify_ it (`WCHAR*`)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to convert from `std::wstring` to `const WCHAR*` (i.e. the returned pointer gives **read-only access** to the string content), then calling `std::wstring::c_str()` method is just fine:

```
std::wstring wstrProcToSearch;
std::wcin >> wstrProcToSearch;  // input std::wstring

// Convert to const WCHAR* (read-only access)
const WCHAR * wpszProcToSearch = wstrProcToSearch.c_str();
```

Instead, if you want to **modify** `std::wstring`'s content, things are different. You can use `&wstr[0]` (where `wstr` is a non-empty instance of `std::wstring`) to access the content of the `std::wstring` (starting from the address of its first characters, and noting that characters are stored contiguously in memory), but you must pay attention to not overrun string's pre-allocated memory.

In general, if you have a `std::wstring` of length `L`, you can access characters from index `0`
to `(L-1)`.

*Before* C++17, [overwriting the terminating `'\0'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740403/legal-to-overwrite-stdstrings-null-terminator) (located at index `L`) was *undefined behavior* (in practice, it's been OK on Visual C++, at least with VC9/VS2008 and VC10/VS2010).

Starting with C++17, overwriting the terminating NUL (`'\0'`) with another NUL has been made [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41310431/1629821) and is no more undefined behavior.

If the string has not the proper size (i.e. it's not big enough for your needs), then you can call `std::wstring::resize()` to make room for new characters (i.e. resizing internal `std::wstring`'s buffer), and then use `&wstr[0]` to read-write `std::wstring`'s content.

Comment: Overwriting the terminatorwith `charT()` is now legal.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Is this an addition from C++17? Could you please provide an official reference? Thanks.

Comment: See the newest and accepted answer on the question you linked, it's in the WP for C++17.

Answer (score 16):

If the string is already the proper length and will not need to be changed, you can get a non-const pointer by taking a pointer to the first character:

```
WCHAR * wpProcToSearch = &wstrProcToSearch[0];
```

This is guaranteed to work in C++11 and there are no known implementations of C++03 where it doesn't.

If you only need a const pointer you should use `c_str`:

```
const WCHAR * wpProcToSearch = wstrProcToSearch.c_str();
```

Comment: You should perhaps add some explanation as to how long these pointers will remain valid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, very good point. Do you know if the standard happens to mention which operations might invalidate the pointer?

Comment: Not my area of expertise. Sorry. This is your field not mine!

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use

`wpProcToSearch = wstrProcToSearch.c_str()`

like you do with a normal std::string.

Comment: thanks, i used  wpProcToSearch =  (WCHAR *)wstrProcToSearch.c_str() since .c_str() creates a const wchar_t

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this approach:

```
wstring str = L"Hallo  x     y   111 2222  3333 rrr 4444   ";
wchar_t* psStr = &str[0];
```

It is quite simple but you can not change the length of the string at all. So moving "\0" might not be valid...