# Can't get wchar_t* from wstring

Tags: c++, pointers, wchar-t, wstring

I try to change value of `wchar_t*` variable with function call.

I use pointers ([Changing an array with a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5611832/7323841)) and when assign `char*` to `char*` or `wchar_t*` to `wchar_t*` it works fine. But if I try to get `wstring` value and assign it to `wchar_t*` variable function call yields garbage/nothing.

I try to convert from `wstring` how it was discussed in [How to convert wstring to wchar_t*? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44985451/7323841), [Convert std::wstring to WCHAR*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16113282/7323841) and [std::wstring to wchar_t *](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/78614-std-wstring-wchar_t-*.html).

Code example:

```
#include <xstring>

void newval(wchar_t **w0, wchar_t **w1, wchar_t **w2, wchar_t **w3, const wchar_t **w4) {
    //wchar_t* to wchar_t* works fine
    *w0 = L"new wchar";

    std::wstring ws = L"new wstring";
    *w1 = &ws[0];
    *w2 = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ws.c_str());
    //just in case
    *w3 = (wchar_t*)ws.c_str();
    *w4 = ws.c_str();
}

void main() {
    wchar_t *v0 = L"";
    wchar_t *v1 = L"";
    wchar_t *v2 = L"";
    wchar_t *v3 = L"";
    const wchar_t *v4 = L"";

    newval(&v0, &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4);

    fprintf(stdout, "New wchar_t: %ws", v0);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nNew wchar_t from &wstring[0]: %ws", v1);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nNew wchar_t from const_cast<wchar_t*>(wstring.c_str()): %ws", v2);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nNew wchar_t from (wchar_t*)ws.c_str(): %ws", v3);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nNew wchar_t from wstring.c_str(): %ws", v4);
}
```

Output:

```
New wchar_t: new wchar  
New wchar_t from &wstring[0]:  
New wchar_t from const_cast<wchar_t*>(wstring.c_str()):  
New wchar_t from (wchar_t*)ws.c_str():  
New wchar_t from wstring.c_str():
```

What's wrong with my code and how I can change `wchar_t*` variable using `wstring` value?

P.S. I can't submit question if output isn't formatted as code.

Comment: Why so much pointer usage?  Using a string class should alleviate you from doing things like this, not escalate usage of pointers.  Also, it's most likely garbage data, since `ws` is a local string, and you're hoping that the `c_str()` tied to it somehow is alive after the function call.

Comment: Your ws object is destructed after you exit the function - so all pointers stored to its contents are dangling and should not be used outside this function. This problem has nothing to do with the question you are trying to ask. It is the same as returning pointer to any other local variable - you should not do it.

Comment: Ok, thank you both. I call C++ function which works with `wstring` from C source and  I can't find out how to work with `wstring` in C. So I use `wchar_t*` as input (converting from `wchar_t*` to `wstring` is fine). Copying `wstring` content to pointer to `wchar_t*` variable works well. Thank you again.