# how to pass a string by pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++ programming i was passing string as pointer

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void changeString(string *s) {
    // change s[1] to 'a' inside this function
}

int main(void) {
    string s = "ayush";
    changeString(&s);
    cout<<s;
}
```

i wrote code *s[1] = 'a', but it is showing error. how do i access first character of string inside function "changeString" . please help any support is appreciated.

Comment: `*s[1]` parses as `*(s[1])`. What you want is `(*s)[1]`.

Comment: Prefer the pass by reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), subscript has higher priority than dereference.
So as @dxiv mentioned in comment `*s[1]` is parsed as `*(s[1])`.

So you need to use parenthesis to change priority as `(*s)[1]`.

By the way, using `string::replace` instead of assign operator is [safer way to change string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305897/4294737).

Better yet, IMHO using reference is more c++ way of doing so. Check code below for example.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void changeStringWithReference(string &s) {
    s[3]= 'a';
}

void changeString(string *s) {
    (*s)[1] = 'a';
    // better to use string::replace
}

int main(void) {
    string s = "abcde";
    changeString(&s);
    cout << s << endl;
    changeStringWithReference(s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```