# Changing first and last letter of a 6 letter word in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any other method to change the first letter and last letter of a 6 letter word?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    cout<< "\nEnter a 6 letter word or numbers: ";
    cin>>word;
    word[0]++;
    word[5]++;
    cout << "Result: " << word << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? Yes there are other ways. What is wrong with the way you are using now?

Comment: I was given a suggestion to use if/else or setw, is that possible?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I need 2-3 methods for it. That's the most simple one that came into my mind.

Comment: Well, for starters, you could use an `if` to check if the word has been actutally read and if it has at least 6 letters. Have you already been introduced to iterators? How many member functions of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) do you know?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @churill, I am trying to achieve a different method to change the first letter and last letter of a word to its next.. I'm trying to build it in if/else but don't know how to change its first and last letter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How do you want to use `if/else` here? And why would it change the way you change the first and last character? Is something not working in your program? I smell a [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `string::replace` but it is a pretty roundabout way compared to replacing using the subscript operator.

something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string word;
        cout<< "\nEnter a 6 letter word or numbers: ";
        cin>>word;
        cout<<word;

        string repl = "x";
        word.replace(5,1, repl);      //replace the 5th position with 1 
                                              //character using string repl

        cout << "Result: " << word << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Take a look at http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

[C++, best way to change a string at a particular index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305844/c-best-way-to-change-a-string-at-a-particular-index)

[How to replace one char by another using std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402477/how-to-replace-one-char-by-another-using-stdstring-in-c)