# Is it safe to ever cast the result of string's c_str to a char*?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm in c++ and i'm using a c library which has an api which accepts a char *. It doesn't accept a const char *, even though the data in the char * will not be modified.

Is it safe to get the result of c_str() and cast it to a 'char *' for use with this api?

```
string str = "mydata";
char * cstr = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
c_api_lib_func(cstr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's safe as long as the function you're passing it to does not attempt to modify the contents of the string.

You can even avoid the `const_cast` using

```
c_api_lib_func(&str[0]);
```

Note that this is technically not safe with a pre-C++11 compiler because `std::string` was not required to have contiguous storage for it's internal buffer.

Using `&str[0]`, the function may even modify the contents of the string's internal buffer as long as it leaves the [terminating NULL character alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740403/legal-to-overwrite-stdstrings-null-terminator).

Comment: I cannot see any requirement in C++11 (N3337 actually) that `&str[0]` points to a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Matt Look at [string.access] and [string.accessors]. The first says that `operator[](size())` returns a `charT()` and the second requires that the pointers obtained by `c_str() + i` (or `data() + i`) be numerically equal to that obtained by `&operator[](i)` within the range `[0, size()]` (note that that's a closed range).

Comment: There might be some weasel room to argue that before `data()` has ever been called, `operator[](size())` can refer to a char elsewhere, but it'd be a pretty perverse implementation to actually do that. However, [string.cons]#13 carefully describes `data()` as pointing to an array of `n` elements (not `n+1`). [string.cons]#6 is similar.  Maybe those sections are an oversight.

Comment: @Matt But in that case if you were to call `operator[](size())` first, store that address and then compare it to `data() + size()` the pointers would not be equal. I do wish the standard was a bit more explicit about the whole thing though. Even the rule of not being able to modify the terminating NULL at all is silly, it should be that you cannot set it to something other than a value initialized `charT`.

Comment: OK , I'm convinced now :) I guess the committee has more important fish to fry than this section.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you treat is as strictly read-only, it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: I think it is unsafe since you are not always knowing what's going on in the c_api_lib_func, which must be someone else's library or api. since if the api is written by ourself, we can change the param to const char*.

Answer (score -1):

it is not safe

this code outputs dydata

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "mydata";
    char * cstr = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
    cstr[0] ='d';
    cout <<str << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @billz, thanks for that, I think it is unsafe since you are not always knowing what's going on in the c_api_lib_func, which must be someone else's library or api. since if the api is written by ourself, we can change the param to const char*.

Comment: You should say the cast itself is safe but modify it later on is undefined behavior.

Comment: @michaeltang just because you can't modify it doesn't mean you can't understand it.

Comment: @hobbs，sometimes we can only get the header file and the library,we can not get the source code